# What is the best tools among 1.OMNet++ 2.QUALNET 3.OPNET 4.NS3 5.LTE-SIM for Mobile Edge Computing simulation?

Tags: omnet++, ns-3, lte, opnet

I am doing my research on Mobile Edge Computing (Offloading technique and resource allocation ),I would like to know what is the best tool out of the below list and why .
1.OMNet++
2.QUALNET
3.OPNET
4.NS3
5.LTE-SIM
if possible guide me to know the importance of the each tool in the edge computing research.

need to know who are working on MEC simulations for research .